# Android client for REST web service with basic security

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I have write a simple RESTful web service using basic authentication.I use tips from this page [secureRestWS](http://www.butonic.de/2010/06/18/a-simple-jax-rs-security-context-example-in-glassfish/). They have also created a video and posted on youtube with more details. It works just fine when you open it in browser. You need to write User Name and Password in authorization window.

I have also find a page with android client that call rest web service using httpclient and if the web service is without authentication it works. I am using this example [androidRestWSClient](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/). But I don`t know how to add User Name and Password in this scenario, I tried like :

```
client.AddParam("User Name", "myusername");
client.AddParam("Password", "mypassword");
```

or in header :

```
client.AddHeader("User Name", "myusername");
client.AddHeader("Password", "mypassword");
```

but nothing works. I also try to create url that tell the web service username and password like :

```
http://192.168.1.42/RestWS/resources/helloWorld?username=myusername&password=mypassword
```

I really don`t have a solution for this so if somebody have an example client I would appreciate that.

In webservice I have simple GET method

```
@GET
@Path("/text")
public String getText() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

Do I need to use SecurityContext for username and password? Is it better to create authentication manualy like in this example :

```
http://aruld.info/accessing-restful-services-configured-with-ssl-using-resttemplate/
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using just basic http authentication, then the URL should look like this:

```
http://username:password@192.168.1.42/RestWS/resources/helloWorld
```

Well, here you go:

```
HttpGet httpget;
try{
    httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

    String auth =new String(Base64.encode(( username + ":" + password).getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP));
    httpget.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
    }
```

Comment: For creating url this works for me, so thanks, maybe someone will answer on first question how to add username and password in client or I would just use link in client ... Thanks

Comment: This works for me just fine, i have found it on other page, but cannot answer my own question in 8 hours ... But now everything is just fine, Thanks for help Kaediil...